# Receive and Process Data From The User Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, puppeteer

I want to receive data from the user and make transactions with that data. Do I have to create an html file for this? Or can I do this on one page?

For example

const option = (await frame1.$x('//*[@id = "classname"]/option[text() = "example.com"]'))[0];

I want the user to enter example.com data, how do I get it from the user and change example.com ?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const http = require('http');

    const server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
      console.dir(request.param)

      if (request.method == 'POST') {
        console.log('POST')
        var body = ''
        request.on('data', function(data) {
          body += data
          console.log('Partial body: ' + body)
        })
        request.on('end', function() {
          console.log('Body: ' + body)
          response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
          response.end('post received')
        })
      } else {
        console.log('GET')
        var html = `
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000">Name: 
                            <input type="text" name="name" />
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </form>
                    </body>
                </html>`
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
        response.end(html)
      }
    })

    const port = 3000
    const host = '127.0.0.1'
    server.listen(port, host)
    console.log(`Listening at http://${host}:${port}`);

//this change maybe then?
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false})
  const page = await browser.newPage()


 await page.goto(body.name);
 const iframeHandle = await page.$("frame[name='main']");
 const frame = await iframeHandle.contentFrame();
 const option = (await frame.$x('//*[@id = "classname"]/option[text() = "@body.name"]'))[0];      
})()
```

Comment: Why puppeteer has anything do do with your question?

Comment: I'm using the puppeteer module. I guess it's not possible to input and process data without using the express and body parser module? I don't know how to use puppeteer and express module at the same time.

Comment: Can you post your code you have so far?

Comment: I tried to integrate a code from which I can get data from the user, but I don't know if it's true. Or I don't know how much code should be added to get a single data? should it be an easier way?